# Relation doesn't exist, but it actually does

Tags: orm, sequelize.js

I set up the following tables and I use a many-to-many connection:

```
const Product = sequelize.define('Product',
        {
            name: DataTypes.STRING,
            quantity: DataTypes.INTEGER
        },
        { freezeTableName: true });
    
    const Cart = sequelize.define('Cart',
        {
            customer_name: DataTypes.STRING,
            total: DataTypes.FLOAT
        });
    
    const CartItem = sequelize.define('CartItem', {
        selfGranted: DataTypes.BOOLEAN
    },
        { timestamps: false });
    
    Cart.belongsToMany(Product, { through: CartItem });
    Product.belongsToMany(Cart, { through: CartItem });
```

And when I proceed to get the data, on the first request it sends me `Relation doesn't exist` error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forgot to remove the database re-sync.

```
db.sequelize.sync({ force: true }).then(() => {
console.log("Drop and re-sync db.");
```

});